# Datagridview formatting issues

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I load an XML file, I transfer the data to the dataset and I display with the datagridview1.

I have 3 colums: start, end, and status.

The format of column start is datetime like 8:00 AM

The format of column end is datetime too like 10:00 PM

Status is two values: ok or nok.

I need to compare the datetime system with the start column and the end column, if the date system are between the two value, I display ok in the row. I need to do that for each row. for ok I need to change the background color to green and nok will be red.
could you help me? .... I m lost between the dataset and the datagridview.
thanks a lot

Thank you guys for your help : I modified a little the code, given by you :)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Security.Permissions;


namespace tab
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet(); 
        ds.ReadXml("C:\\Sites.xml"); 
        int count = 0; 
        foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows) 
        { 


            string s1 = dr[0].ToString();
            string s2 = dr[1].ToString();
            string timeSys = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm tt");
            TimeSpan Start = DateTime.ParseExact(s1, "hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).TimeOfDay; 
            TimeSpan End = DateTime.ParseExact(s2, "hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).TimeOfDay;
            TimeSpan Now = DateTime.ParseExact(timeSys, "hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).TimeOfDay;

            if (Start.Hours < Now.Hours && Now.Hours < End.Hours) 
            { 
               ds.Tables[0].Rows[count][2] = "OK"; 

            } 
            else 
            { 
                ds.Tables[0].Rows[count][2] = "NOK"; 
            } 
            count++; 
        }

        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

        for (int icount = 0; icount < dataGridView1.RowCount-1; icount++) 
        { 
            DataGridViewRow theRow = dataGridView1.Rows[icount]; 

            if (theRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString() == "OK") 

                theRow.Cells[2].Style.BackColor = Color.Green; 
            else 

                theRow.Cells[2].Style.BackColor = Color.Red; 
        }

    } 

        }
    }
```

I have still an issue, I didn't see the color displayed in the datagridview.

Comment: This question needs a meaningful title, one that isn't just a repeat of the tags, but I don't understand the question well enough to offer one.  Somebody?

Comment: If the color question is the only one remaining, open a new one. And look at the CellFormatting event. It is the right moment to define a cell's color (by e.CellStyle.BackColor, for example).

Comment: In case this worked, do remember to mark it as answer (use the tick mark next to the answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
       DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds.ReadXml(@"...\\..\\Sites.xml");
        int count = 0;
        foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {


            string s1 = dr[0].ToString(); 
            string s2 = dr[1].ToString();
            TimeSpan ts1 = DateTime.ParseExact(s1, "hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).TimeOfDay;
            TimeSpan ts2 = DateTime.ParseExact(s2, "hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).TimeOfDay;
            TimeSpan now = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;

            if (ts1.Hours >= 8 && ts2.Hours <= 22)
            {
               ds.Tables[0].Rows[count][2] = "OK";

            }
            else
            {
                ds.Tables[0].Rows[count][2] = "NOK";
            }
            count++;
        }

        grdvw_wnfrm.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

        for (int icount = 0; icount < grdvw_wnfrm.RowCount-1; icount++)
        {
            DataGridViewRow theRow = grdvw_wnfrm.Rows[icount];

            if (theRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString() == "OK")

                theRow.Cells[2].Style.BackColor = Color.Green;
            else

                theRow.Cells[2].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
        }

    }
```

Comment: All next you need to have is XML file and rest is the change in condition.

Comment: yes, I modified the condition, it's perfect. I have still an issue to display the colors. Do I need to activate something for that?

Comment: No since you are using Windows forms dont need to activate any thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can try subscribing to the `DataBindingComplete` event of the DataGridView

Then loop through the rows

```
string s1 = "08:00 AM"; // this corresponds to your start value in grid
string s2 = "10:00 PM";
TimeSpan start = DateTime.ParseExact(s1, "hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).TimeOfDay;
TimeSpan end = DateTime.ParseExact(s2, "hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).TimeOfDay;
TimeSpan now = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
```

you can now set the cell color using somewhat on these lines

```
if(now > start && now < end)
    row.Cells[colname].Style.BackColor = Color.Green;
```

Comment: This is assuming you have the time in the proper zone else it would be best suited in getting now as `.UtcNow`.